# function definition does't receive the array values using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have one function call `remove_certificate_packages($certificate_id, array_keys($package_id))` this will invoke the below function

```
function remove_certificate_packages($certificate_id, $package_id)
{    
    if (is_numeric($package_id)) // so this is list of package id:s
        $package_id = array($package_id);

    if (!$package_id) return true;

    **notify_package_unlinked($certificate_id,array_keys($package_id));**//one more func call

    return true;
}
```

in this function, I have one more function call "notify_package_unlinked" I need to pass the "$package_id". It will call the appropriate function but the problem is, in the "notify_package_unlinked" function the value is showing "Array". What is the problem? Could you please help

```
function notify_package_unlinked($certificate_id,$package_id) 
{
      $query="select id,filename,version from packages where id =$package_id";
      $res = db_query($query);
      $package= db_fetch_object($res);

      $packid=$package->id;
      $packname=$package->filename;
      $packversion=$package->version;
      print "$packid"; // here it is printing the value"Array"
 }
```

Comment: Anybody tell how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Anyone please help

Comment: I got my output using for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my output using foreach loop .

```
foreach($package_id as $id){$pack=$id;}
```

Comment: with the help of myself